# Reusing Django Cursor for raw queries

Tags: python, mysql, django, pymysql

I have a little application which is supposed to work as a querying service layer to many SQL databases.

Based on a parameter in the request body the application decides which DB the query should be executed on. Hence, it obtains a cursor to the specific DB. After executing the query, it closes the cursor.

Here is the code

```
def get_cursor(request_body):
    cursor = None
    if  request_body['DB'] >= 'xyz':
        cursor = connections["hotDB"].cursor()
    else:
        cursor = connections["coldDB"].cursor()
    return cursor
```

There is no model in the application. All the queries are raw queries.

Obtaining the cursor and closing it are expensive operation and makes the request take long time.

Is there a way to cache the cursor and reuse it for later requests.

Comment: "There is no model in the application. All the queries are raw queries." then don't use django

Comment: what do you suggest? Flask?

Comment: if it's raw queries use raw python.